# Laravel-5 redirect within authorize() function on form requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible for me to create a redirect from within the authorize() function on a request?  I have tried the following code, but it doesn't fulfill the redirect request.  Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Reserve;
use Cookie;
use Config;

class ClassVoucherCheckoutRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(Reserve $reserve, Cookie $cookie)
    {
        if((!$cookie->has(Config::get('app.cookie_name'))) || ($reserve->where('cookie_id', $cookie->get(Config::get('app.cookie_name')))->count() == 0))
        {
            return redirect()->to('butchery-voucher')->withErrors('Your reservation has expired.  Places can only be held for up to 30 minutes.');
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea if that is actually your problem, but you can not send a HTTP redirect after any tiny bit of content has been sent. So if the code comes after the `<html>` tag, or perhaps only a space before the `<?php`), or an `echo`, it will not work.

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: Keep in mind, that the authorize function is not at all intended for this purpose. As you can see in the doc block it is intended to return a boolean true or false. False in the case that the calling user is generally not allowed to fire this request. In your case it depends on some cookie values, so you should touch this problem either on middleware level or on custom validation level.

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same issue, I did not find any solution yet but I have do this by an another way, I know this is not the right solution but may be help for now.

**My problem is: I need to register an user if any other user with same `fb_id` did not exists in database. But I was unable to check this condition because the middelware execute before the controller and it returns me the `fb_id` already taken error.**

**This is my `UserController`:**

```
public function createUser (UserRequest $request) {

 /** here I need to redirect user if the given `fb_id` is already exists
     before it was always returning the `fb_id` exists error before executing 
     the following code, because all input filtered by the `UserRequest` middleware 
     I have changed the `UserRequest.php` to execute the following code.
 **/
        $fb_id = Input::get('fb_id');
        $user = $this->user->getUserWhereFbIdIn([$fb_id]);

        if(sizeof($user) > 0){
            return Response::json(['result' => true, 'error' => false, 'message' => 'User exists', 'data' => $user]);
        }


        // insert user code is here
    }
```

**UserRequest.php:**

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}


public function rules()
{
    $fb_id = Input::get('fb_id');
    $user = User::where('fb_id', $fb_id)->get()->toArray();

    if(sizeof($user) > 0){
        return [];
    } 
    return [
        'fb_id' => 'required|unique:users',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users',
        'image' => 'required',
        'device_id' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Comment: This is working! (+1 for that ) but somehow, this does not feel 'clean' for me... At least you have sort of duplicated code. I think I would go with a custom middleware instead.

Comment: Yes I know this is not the best solution of this issue, I am trying to solve this in propar manner, but it might take some time, till then we can use this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most elegant solution is to make the `authorize()` return `false` when you want to redirect, and override the `forbiddenResponse()` method on the `FormRequest` class. The  drawback is that you'll either have to perform the condition logic twice, or set a state variable.

```
class MyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return Auth::user()->hasNoEmail() ? false : true;
    }

    public function forbiddenResponse(): Response
    {
        if Auth::user()->hasNoEmail() return redirect(route('user.should_provide_email'));

        return parent::forbiddenResponse();
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Of course, the argument could be made that such redirects should always take place in a middleware applied to specific groups of routes, but having the option to do it in a Request class can be nice.